# (What you are going to do is...) or (What you are going to do are...)

Tags: grammar

Suppose, I want to mention what someone is going to do and they have to do more than one, which one is more appropriate between:

> [1] What you are going to do **is**: clean your room, sweep the floor and
> do the dishes.

> [2] What you are going to do **are**: clean your room, sweep the floor and
> do the dishes.

Comment: **Is** "is" singular and **are** is plural. The 2nd example is better than the 1st one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's closer to your first example, but should be:

> What **you are going** to do is clean your room, sweep the floor and
> do the dishes.

Comment: I've edited the question. Thanks for pointing that out. So the correct verb to be is 'is' there?

Comment: Yes, 'is' is correct.